# How do you copy objects in Swift?

Tags: swift, copy

I have the following class:

```
class Client {
  let name: String
  let age: Int

  init(name: String, age: Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
  }
}

let wrongClient = Client(name: "John", age: 9)
```

How can I create a new version of `wrongClient` with the right age?

I want something like the following:

```
let rightClient = Client(wrongClient, age: 42)
```

For example OCaml lets developers do the following:

```ml
type client = {
  name : string;
  age : int;
}

let wrong_client = {name = "John"; age = 25}
let right_client = {wrong_client with age = 42}
```

Or in Scala:

```scala
case class Client(name: String, age: Int)

val wrongClient = Client(name: "John", age: 9)
val rightClient = wrongClient.copy(age=42)
```

**EDIT**

I want to experiment with data immutability and data sharing with Swift.

Because immutable data imply "generating" values from other values, "copying" objects can happen often. So my question really is : how can I easily construct new objects from other objects with Swift?

**EDIT 2**

I'm currently looking at [Swiftz' lenses](https://github.com/typelift/swiftz/blob/master/Swiftz/Lens.swift).

Comment: Why add `OCaml` is added as a tag?

Comment: @JacksonTale I'm sorry it was just to see if it fixes the syntax highlighting.

Comment: ah ok. I asked because [Swift is not a functional programming language](http://robnapier.net/swift-is-not-functional)

Comment: @JacksonTale thanks for the link! Although Swift hasn't been thought to be used as a functional language, I find it kind of awkward to have some tools to build immutable data structures, but nearly none to easily work with them.

Comment: I presume that Swift is just like Java 8 or Python, an imperative language with some functional points?

Answer (score 7):

You can implement Client as a `struct` instead of a `class` since `struct` is always passed by value.

```
struct Client {
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

var wrongClient = Client(name: "John", age: 18)
var rightClient = wrongClient
rightClient.age = 99
```

Assigning wrongClient to rightClient creates a copy. When you update the `age` of rightClient, wrongClient still remains 18.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't any defined short-hand for it.  I'd recommend something like:

```
class Client {
    let name: String
    let age: Int

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    private init(from: Client, age:Int) {
        self.name = from.name
        self.age = age
    }

    func withAge(age:Int) -> Client {
        return Client(from: self, age: age)
    }
}

let right_client = Client(name: "John", age: 9)
let wrong_client = right_client.withAge(42)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's working for me <3

Answer (score 2):

You could add another `init` method.

```
   required init(name: String, age: Int) {
       self.name = name
       self.age = age
   }

   convenience init(from: Client, withAge: Int) {
       self.init(name: from.name, age: withAge)
   }
```

Comment: Is there a way to automate this behaviour for every classes?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2):

There has to be a better way, but my current solution is this:

```
   init(name: String, age: Int) {
       self.name = name
       self.age = age
   }

   init(from: Client, name: Int? = nil, age: Int? = nil) {
       self.name = name ?? Client.name
       self.age = age ?? Client.age
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

In our Swift code generator we automatically include a copy constructor for every class. The generator is here: https://github.com/eclipse/agileuml

An example of the constructor, working with inheritance, is:

```
class Person
{ init() { }

  init(copyFrom: Person) {
    self.name = copyFrom.name
    self.age = copyFrom.age
    self.parents = copyFrom.parents
  }

  func copy() -> Person
  { let res : Person = Person(copyFrom: self)
    return res
  }

  var name : String = ""
  var age : Int64 = 0
  var parents : [Person] = []
}

class Staff : Person
{ override init()
  { super.init() }

  init(copyFrom: Staff) {
    super.init(copyFrom: copyFrom)
    self.staffNo = copyFrom.staffNo
    self.boss = copyFrom.boss
  }

  override func copy() -> Staff
  { let res : Staff = Staff(copyFrom: self)
    return res
  }

  var staffNo : Int = 0
  var boss : [Staff] = []
}
```

Sequences, sets and maps are also copied element-by-element.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make your class conform to NSCopying. This isn't strictly required,
   but it makes your intent clear.
2. Implement the method copy(with:), where the actual copying happens.
3. Call copy() on your object.

Here's an example of a Person class that conforms fully to the NSCopying protocol:

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCopying {

  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String
  var age: Int

  init(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int) {
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.age = age
  }

  func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
    let copy = Person(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, age: age)
    return copy
  }
```

Note that copy(with:) is implemented by creating a new Person object using the current person's information.

With that done, you can test out your copying like this:

```
let paul = Person(firstName: "Paul", lastName: "Hudson", age: 36)
let sophie = paul.copy() as! Person

sophie.firstName = "Sophie" sophie.age = 6

print("\(paul.firstName) \(paul.lastName) is \(paul.age)")
print("\(sophie.firstName) \(sophie.lastName) is \(sophie.age)")
```

source: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-copy-objects-in-swift-using-copy

Answer (score -1):

If you need copy of an array, just try it with filter and use something which is always true like:

```
let oldTagValueKey = self.tagValueKey.filter({ $0.value.characters.isEmpty == false })
```