# Create a value type property in Class iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

We all know that properties of class is always is reference type, but is there any possible way to create a value type property in class?

Class :

```
class Color {
    var name : String!
    init(name : String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Utilisation :

```
    let red = Color(name: "Red")
    let yellow = red
    print("red \(red.name ?? "")")  // prints Red
    print("yellow \(yellow.name ?? "")") // prints Red


   // assigning a new value to yellow instance

    yellow.name = "Yellow"
    print("red \(red.name ?? "")")  // prints Yellow
    print("yellow \(yellow.name ?? "")") // prints Yellow
```

after assigning value to yellow instance it is changing the value red instance as well.

Comment: "properties of class is always is reference type" Not true. If you have _ever_ declared an `Int` or `String` property in a class, you'd know,

Comment: Hi @Sweeper, thank you for quick reply , i edit my question please check

Comment: That has nothing to do with whether the class has reference type or value type properties. It has everything to do with whether the class `Color` _itself_ is a reference type or value type. And well, classes are always reference types, so the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

A class is meant to be reference type, so you can try to make a copy from an instance of a class.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174531/how-do-you-copy-objects-in-swift) can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Color: NSObject, NSCopying {
            var name : String!
            init(name : String) {
                self.name = name
            }
        
            func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
                let copy = Color(name: name)
                return copy
            }
   }

    let red = Color(name: "red")
    let yellow = red.copy() as! Color
    
    print("red \(red.name ?? "")")  // prints Red
    print("yellow \(yellow.name ?? "")") // prints Red
    
    // assigning a new value to yellow instance
    
     yellow.name = "Yellow"
     print("red \(red.name ?? "")")  // prints red
     print("yellow \(yellow.name ?? "")") // prints Yellow
```

- Make your class conform to NSCopying. This isn't strictly required,    but it makes your intent clear.
- Implement the method copy(with:),    where the actual copying
  happens.
- Call copy() on your object.